# Textarea scroll event not being caught

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `textarea` that contains terms & conditions and it's scrollable. When I scroll down the `textarea` I want to enable a checkbox which the user can check and continue. The problem is it isn't working.

```
<textarea name="terms" runat="server" id="terms" style="resize:none" disabled="disabled" rows="20" cols="10">
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_termos" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#terms").scroll(function() {
      alert("AI O CARALHO")
      if ($("#terms").scrollTop() > 10) {
        $('#chk_termos').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $('#chk_termos').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I even scroll to get the `alert("AI O CARALHO")` it just doesn't show, so I guess that the function isn't even working.

Comment: You know you've set your `textarea` to be `disabled`, right?

Comment: It really affects?

Comment: Uh, yes. If it's disabled, you can't scroll it.

Comment: omg it affected, how to I prevent them from writting on the Textarea tho?

Comment: I was scrolling it with the disable on

Comment: Can you make it readonly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `textarea` set to be disabled, which will disable all the functionality within it.

Instead, don't use a `textarea` at all and just use a `div` element, since they aren't editable by default in the first place. You've also got your enabled/disabled commands reversed in the `if` branches.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#terms").scroll(function () {
     //alert("AI O CARALHO")
     if ($("#terms").scrollTop() > 10) {
        $('#chk_termos').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else {
        $('#chk_termos').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#terms { height: 5em; overflow-y:scroll; width:25%; border:1px solid #e0e0e0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terms">
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
 Read all of this and scroll to the bottom<br>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_termos" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, the problem was that I was using the TextArea, using this and formating it's CSS it's much easier and simple, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works in Chrome. In all other browsers `disabled` form elements do not raise `scroll` events, so your logic never fires.

To fix this you could use `readonly` instead, so that the user cannot amend the content of the `textarea`, yet it still fires the `scroll` event as required:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#terms").scroll(function() {
    $('#chk_termos').prop('disabled', $(this).scrollTop() > 10);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="terms" id="terms" style="resize:none" readonly="true" rows="20" cols="10">
Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sita amet consectetur adipscing elit. 
</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_termos" name="chk_thermos" />
```